# Как сделать PDF с редиректом на какой либо сайт?

Tags: javascript

Как можно сделать пдфку с редиректом на какой либо сайт?

Answer (score 2):

Никак. На то это и PDF, то есть документ.
К тому же, этого и не может быть из-за соображений безопасности. Если нужно редиректить пользователя на сайте, используйте для этого Apache/Nginx и соответствующие правила.